# C strcmp() returns positive when comparing String with char pointer

Tags: c, string, while-loop, strcmp

I have the following code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char *buf;

    buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * 512);


    while(strcmp(buf, "Exit!") != 0 )
    {
        printf("Enter something:");
        fgets(buf, sizeof(char) * 512, stdin);
        printf("You entered %s\n", buf);

        printf("%d\n", strcmp(buf, "Exit!"));

    }

}
```

The behavior I want is for the `while` loop to terminate when the user enters the specified `string`. From what I understand, I am able to use a `char` pointer to represent a `string` in C. I am storing the user input using `fgets()` and comparing using the `strcmp()` function. I added a debug statement that prints out the result of this comparison and it returns a positive integer when I enter "Exit!" which should terminate the while loop.

Could someone explain what I am missing? I believe it has something to do with a new line character or the C-String terminator `\0`. How do I get the while loop to terminate when the user enters "Exit"?

Comment: `fgets` read *and includes* the trailing `'\n'` with each line it reads.

Comment: You should also `break` the loop if `fgets` returns `NULL`. Without that check, the code will go into an infinite loop if the user presses the key combination that generates `EOF`. That key combination is control-D on unix systems, and control-Z on windows.

Comment: Also, after the `malloc`, you should have the line `buf[0] = '\0';` That avoids the (extremely unlikely) chance that the buffer returned by `malloc` contains the string `"Exit!"`

Answer (score 1):

It is because `fgets` retains the `newline` that was entered from the keyboard, or marked the end of the line in the text file.

One simple way to remove it is like this:

```
#include <string.h>

//...

buf [ strcspn(buf, "\r\n") ] = 0;   // remove trailing newline etc
```

Comment: Surely that is a bad idea, because if the pattern isn't in the string, you could overflow buf by one byte?

Comment: @SectoKia it is completely safe. If neither `\n` or `\r` are present, it overwrites the exisiting `'\0'` terminator, otherwise it overwrites the first match.